# Cannot connect to SQL Server after upgrade from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2022 Visual Basic Application

Tags: sql-server, vba, connection

I have a Visual Studio VB app that uses the string below to connect to SQL Server.

```vb
Dim strconnect As String = "data source=INFO-COR-SQL01;initial catalog=infocast;integrated security=true"
Dim conn As SqlConnection
conn = New SqlConnection(strconnect)

Dim strcom As SqlCommand
'Dim strcom2 As SqlCommand

Try
    strcom = New SqlCommand("select Conference from MainConference ORDER BY Conference ", conn)
    conn.Open()
```

I recently upgraded from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2022 and receive this error message when I try connecting to the new database:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=0x80131904
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
> StackTrace:

How can I modify the connection string previously used to connect to SQL Server 2022?

I tried connecting using TCP/IP and that did not work

Comment: Did you upgrade in-place or perform a new installation? With a new install, make sure you run SQL Server Configuration Manager to allow TCP/IP connections.